# Delete N number of old records from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a **LoginTime** table like this:

```
id | user_id | datetime
1  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:01
2  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:02  
3  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:03  
4  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:04  
5  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:05  
6  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:06  
7  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:07  
8  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:08  
9  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:09  
10 |   2     | 2011-01-19 18:51:10
```

I want to keep only 5 latest(by 'datetime' column) records and delete all previous records where `user_id=1`

Is it possible to achieve this with one mysql query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this will work...

```
DELETE FROM LoginTime WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id
     WHERE user_id = 1
     ORDER BY datetime DESC
     LIMIT 0, 5
)
```

Comment: `WHERE user_id=1` and `ORDER BY datetime`

Comment: **Error:** `SQL error: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3]This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery', SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect` ....... Is it mysql version error or odbc connection version error.

Comment: I guess you'll have to try something else :/

Comment: mysql doesn't support limit in subqueries.

Answer (score 8):

```
DELETE 
FROM LoginTime 
WHERE user_id = 1 
ORDER BY datetime ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Go for that, it's the most simple and best solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete LoginTime
from 
  LoginTime
left join
  (
    select id
    from LoginTime
    where user_id=1
    order by `datetime` desc
    limit 5
  ) as not_to_delete
on LoginTime.id=not_to_delete.id
where
  not_to_delete.id is null;
```

**PS:** please don't use CamelCase for table name, and avoid using reserved keywords for the column name

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But here is a problem.. If I use `user_id=3` that does not exists in table then it is deleting all records of table.

Comment: you can add in count in the left join, and the where is checking count>=1

Answer (score 0):

```
delete LoginTime
from 
  LoginTime

left join
  (
    select id
    from LoginTime
    where user_id=1
    order by datetime desc
    limit 5
  ) as not_to_delete
on LoginTime.id=not_to_delete.id

left join
  (
    select id
    from LoginTime
    where user_id=1
  ) as existance
on LoginTime.id=existance.id

where
  not_to_delete.id is null and existance.id is not null;
```