# SQL DELETE all rows apart from last N rows for each unique value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Here's a tough one,
How would I delete all but the last, say 3 rows, for each unique value in a different field?

Here's a visual of the problem:

```
id | otherfield
---------------
 1 | apple      <- DELETE
 2 | banana     <- KEEP
 3 | apple      <- DELETE
 4 | apple      <- KEEP
 5 | carrot     <- KEEP
 6 | apple      <- KEEP
 7 | apple      <- KEEP
 8 | banana     <- KEEP
```

How would I accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: Found something close, but doesn't base on each unique value in the other field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720996/delete-n-number-of-old-records-from-table-in-mysql

Comment: Sounds like something the WINDOW extension was designed to solve but I don't know enough about it or its support in mysql to answer your question.

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: Not alot at the moment, <100. But it will grow...eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Non tested, but something along these lines might work:

```
DELETE t.*
FROM table t JOIN (
    SELECT id
        @rowNum := IF(@otherfield <> otherfield, 1, @rowNum + 1) rn,
        @otherfield := otherfield otherfield
    FROM (
        SELECT id, otherfield
        FROM table
        ORDER BY otherfield, id DESC
    ) t, (SELECT @otherfield := NULL, @rowNum := -1) dm
) rs ON t.id = rs.id
WHERE rs.rn > 3
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table history JOIN ( SELECT id @rowNum := IF(@page <> page, 1, @ro' at line 2


DELETE history . * FROM TABLE history JOIN (
SELECT id@rowNum := IF( @page <> 
PAGE , 1, @rowNum +1 ) rn, @page := 
PAGE PAGE 
FROM (

SELECT id, 
PAGE 
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY PAGE , id DESC
)history, (

SELECT @page := NULL , @rowNum := -1
)dm
)rs ON history.id = rs.id
WHERE rs.rn >3

Comment: @user546911 Replace `table` with your table name. do not keep the word `table` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete MyTable
Where Id In (
            Select Id
            From    (
                    Select Id
                        , (Select COUNT(*)
                            From MyTable As T2
                            Where T2.OtherField = T.OtherField
                                And T2.Id > T.Id) As Rnk
                    From MyTable As T
                    ) As Z
            Where Z.Rnk > 2     
            )
```

Another version which might be a bit faster:

```
Delete MyTable
Where Id In (
            Select T.Id
            From MyTable As T
                Left Join MyTable As T2
                    On T2.OtherField = T.OtherField
                        And T2.Id > T.Id
            Group By T.Id
            Having Count(T2.Id) > 2
            )
```

Comment: Taking the 2nd version:

#1054 - Unknown column 'T2.page' in 'on clause'

DELETE FROM history WHERE id IN (
SELECT T.id
FROM history AS T
LEFT JOIN history AS T2 ON T2.page = T.page
AND T2.id > T.id
GROUP BY T.id
HAVING COUNT( T2.id ) >2
)

Comment: @user646911 - Nowhere in my query is `T2.page` referenced, so I do not understand how you could have gotten that error.

Comment: @user646911 - The error implies that it does not find a `page` column in the `history` table. Are you sure it is spelled and perhaps capitalized correctly?